# How can I open websites with selenium/webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, driver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

error code: Executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a service object.

The code above begins to open a Google Chrome tab but does not pick a user, and it will stop where Google Chrome shows all your users. I've tried using a specific profiles path but I've gotten various errors. If someone is able to resolve this issue I would appreciate it, I would like to open the Chrome tab as a guest.

Comment: I'm assuming if I dig deep enough into finding the paths for specific users it would probably work(although I tried this by using the profile path from Chrome::versions), but as far as I understand (beginner coder), this is pretty basic stuff that should run smoothly.

Comment: what error does it say?

Comment: as I know it is NOT error but only warning. Real error should stop program. At this moment you can still use `Chrome(path)` but in next versions it may raise error (and stop program) if you don't use `Chrome(service=Service(path))`

Comment: error code: Executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a service object. @SergeySakharovskiy

Comment: Correct its not an error its actually working but instead of opening the website I have in line 4 (facebook) it just opens a google tab without picking a profile then doesn't go any further. Basically as if the line "driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')" isn't even in the code. If I take it out that line of code it does the same thing. @furas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your question has two parts. You are trying to figure out the webdriver and the user profile path. Allow me to answer both of these questions for you.

In the latest version of Selenium the `executable_path` parameter has been deprecated. Service objects containing the executable path are now required. There are two options for this.

## Service objects

### Option #1: Use your executable path

Append this import to your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```

Then, include the service object as such:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"))
```

### Option #2: Let web driver manager handle it

This is great for when the driver becomes outdated. No need to redownload the driver.

First, go to the project directory in your terminal. If you are using PyCharm, there is no need to traverse to the directory, as you are already in the project directory.

Use pip to install web driver manager:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Now, there is no need to enter an executable path:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
```

## Selecting a user profile

This is fairly simple. First, go to chrome and enter `chrome://version/` into the URL address bar. You will see the profile path. It will look like this `C:\Users\yourprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

Then, include the following chrome options as such:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\yourprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Comment: I dont know who you are....but I will find you...and I will thank you... (Hope you get the movie reference)

Comment: Haha I love Taken. Be sure to upvote this and mark it as the correct answer

Comment: My account needs to age a little more before I'm able to upvote, as soon as I can I will.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest you rename the question title to something more specific for future users who also struggle with this

Comment: Okay no worries

Comment: If you have some free time, please check out my most recent question, I believe you might be able to answer it as well..Thank you very much. @Jonathan Taylor

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
The service is the path to the chrome driver you can download.
The chrome driver can be downloaded here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/chromedriver')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()


  [1]: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
```

Comment: When I switch to that and add my chromedriver path in line 3 I get the error code: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home